# How to intercept Apache CXF Servlet exceptions

Tags: java, rest, cxf

I have developed a REST service using Apache CXF and notice that if I send invalid characters in the URL, the CXF servlet throws back the following exception before it gets to my code:

```
Servlet failed with Exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:841)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.BaseUrlHelper.getBaseURL(BaseUrlHelper.java:49)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.getBaseURL(ServletController.java:73)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.updateDestination(ServletController.java:82)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:162)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:137)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:239)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:164)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:215)
```

This results in a 500 status code being returned to the client.

I would ideally like to intercept this exception and return a 400 Bad Request status code to the client but I am unable to work out how to do this.

Any help much appreciated!

Many thanks

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem? Did you check the CXF documentation: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html

Answer (score 1):

The way I did this is by means of an interceptor. 
If an error has occurred during initial processing of a request, a framework response (and of course status code) will be put on the message pipe.
So you could for example write a interceptor on "marshall" phase, check if there already is a response and rewrite to your own response.

```
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {

    if (message.getExchange().get(Response.class) != null) {
         //build your response and put it on the exchange
         message.getExchange().put(Response.class, yourResponse);
    }
```